# link analysis using nutch

Tags: hyperlink, nutch, web-crawler

I am new to nutch. I have crawled some urls using nutch. Now I want to get linkrank of them. I read about it [here](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NewScoring). The problem is that I can't create webGraphdb. In my crawl directory I have `linkdb`, `segments` and `crawldb` directory. I need it when I run the command

```
./nutch -webgraph -segment <seg name> -segmentDir <seg dir> webgrapgdb??
```

I need to give the address of webgraphdb. How should I generate it. My nutch version is 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webgraph command is for generating or updating of webgraphs. You can pass anything as the value of webgraphdb argument. If a directory with that name does not exist, nutch will create one for you.